# "IDE error occurred" after creating a new project in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

When I create a new project in android studio it says after it is done creating: "IDE error occurred"

here is the image of my android studio after creating a new project:

[image: image 1]

and here is the stack trace:
 [image: image 2]

note: I can't find my xml code or java code (MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml) any where in my project, it didn't create them.

**I tried reinstalling android studio and updating it**, but that didn't work. any help please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184378/9166855

Comment: @PrajwalW  I have already tried this but nothing worked...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create project with name without any spaces in it?
Also can suggest to delete cashes folder in AndroidStudio\system or symply try to use Clean Project in Build menu.