# Android Studio - New Activity appears to build/sync but not visible

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tEG7.jpg

In this video you will will see me trying to create a new empty activity to add to my project. I right click, new, activity, empty activity. Then it appears to say it is syncing? It then says Gradle sync finished. However I have no activity under the folder I added or any that I can see. Any suggestions how to fix this? Thanks!

Edit: Never mind video looks so blurry there and it doesnt even show the drop downs... sorry

[Creating the activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Fmc.png)

Comment: In your video can't see the point where you create the Activity, only able to see the Android Studio window.

Comment: Ya I realized that, hence the edit comment.. not sure how else to do it. But process was same as what I described so if that isnt enough I will just have to try to research more :/

Comment: Did you check the actual directory in your file system whether the activity is there or not?

Comment: I don't see it there either

Comment: Did you try doing the following. In Android Studio go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart?

Comment: Tried it, still nothing appears

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691493/cannot-create-new-activity-in-android-studio/51438353

https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/issues/67

See if any of these help. Can you see any event logs?

Comment: It says gradle sync started, then gradle sync finished. Everytime I try that is all that is in the event log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63396653/5841416 This guy was facing a very similar issue.